# Redux saga multiple api calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a bunch of action watchers of my api calls using redux-saga. The thing is I would like to make **ONE** action watcher which fire all these action watchers to fetch all the api without having to repeat the codes I already have. If one of the watcher return a rejected Promise, it should cancel all the other watchers. What's the best way of doing this?

```
function* watchFetchUsers() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_USERS]);
        try {
            const users = yield call(api.fetchUserData);
            yield put({ type:FETCH_USERS, payload: users });    
        } catch (err) {
            yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
            return err;
        }
    }
}

function* watchFetchDepartments() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_DEPARTMENTS]);
        try {
            const departments = yield call(api.fetchDepartmentData);
            yield put({ type:FETCH_DEPARTMENTS, payload: departments });    
        } catch (err) {
            yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
            return err;
        }
    }
}

function* watchFetchPositions() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_POSITIONS]);
        try {
            const positions = yield call(api.fetchPositionData);
            yield put({ type:FETCH_POSITIONS, payload: positions });    
        } catch (err) {
            yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
            return err;
        }
    }
}

function* watchFetchBanks() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_BANKS]);
        try {
            const banks = yield call(api.fetchBankData);
            yield put({ type:FETCH_BANKS, payload: banks });    
        } catch (err) {
            yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
            return err;
        }
    }
}

function* watchFetchAuthenticatedUser() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_AUTHENTICATED_USER]);
        try {
            const user = yield call(api.fetchAuthenticatedUser);
            yield put({ type:FETCH_AUTHENTICATED_USER, payload: user });    
        } catch (err) {
            yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
            return err;
        }
    }
}

export default function* fetchData() {
    yield [
        fork(watchFetchUsers),
        fork(watchFetchDepartments),
        fork(watchFetchPositions),
        fork(watchFetchBanks),
        fork(watchFetchAuthenticatedUser)
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
export function* watchFetchAll() {
  while(true) {
    // const {type} = yield take(['FETCH_A', 'FETCH_B', ...]);
    const {type} = yield take(action => /^FETCH_/.test(action.type));
    console.log('type %s', type);
    try {
      const data = yield call(api.fetch, type);
      console.log('data', data);
      yield put({type, payload: data})
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      yield put({ type: 'SIGNOUT', status: error })
    }
  }
}

export default function* fetchData() {
    yield *watchFetchAll();
}
```

The simple api implementation:

```
const api = {
  fetch(type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'FETCH_A': return Promise.resolve({result: 'Fetched A type'});
      case 'FETCH_B': return Promise.resolve({result: 'Fetched B type'});
      // other cases
      default: console.log(`Unknown type ${type}`);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The forked task's error is propagated to parent tasks.
I'm not sure if the below is what you want. But maybe it will work.

```
function* watchFetchUsers() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_USERS]);
        const users = yield call(api.fetchUserData);
        yield put({ type:FETCH_USERS, payload: users });    
    }
}

function* watchFetchDepartments() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_DEPARTMENTS]);
        const departments = yield call(api.fetchDepartmentData);
        yield put({ type:FETCH_DEPARTMENTS, payload: departments });    
    }
}

function* watchFetchPositions() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_POSITIONS]);
        const positions = yield call(api.fetchPositionData);
        yield put({ type:FETCH_POSITIONS, payload: positions });    
    }
}

function* watchFetchBanks() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_BANKS]);
        const banks = yield call(api.fetchBankData);
        yield put({ type:FETCH_BANKS, payload: banks });    
    }
}

function* watchFetchAuthenticatedUser() {
    while(true) {
        yield take([FETCH_AUTHENTICATED_USER]);
        const user = yield call(api.fetchAuthenticatedUser);
        yield put({ type:FETCH_AUTHENTICATED_USER, payload: user });   
    }
}

export default function* fetchData() {
    while (true) {
        let tasks;
        try {
           tasks = yield [
                fork(watchFetchUsers),
                fork(watchFetchDepartments),
                fork(watchFetchPositions),
                fork(watchFetchBanks),
                fork(watchFetchAuthenticatedUser)
            ];
            yield join(...tasks)
        } catch (e) {
           yield cancel(...tasks);
           yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to restore tasks,

```
//....
export default function* fetchData() {
    try {
        yield [
            fork(watchFetchUsers),
            fork(watchFetchDepartments),
            fork(watchFetchPositions),
            fork(watchFetchBanks),
            fork(watchFetchAuthenticatedUser)
        ];
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer called `Parallel Task` wherein you call 2 or more api at the same time, also efficient to handle than to this (example below)

```js
// wrong, effects will be executed in sequence
const users = yield call(fetch, '/users')
const repos = yield call(fetch, '/repos')

//instead, try this one
import { all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

const [users, repos] = yield all([
  call(fetch, '/users'),
  call(fetch, '/repos')
])
```

for more information regards with your issue, I prefer to read more about sync and async of redux saga, [Redux-Saga Parallel task](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls/) and [Non-Blocking Call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls/)